# Having trouble with changing equations.

Tags: integration

I have to find the are bounded by the graphs of equations: the first graph is $y=x^2$, and the second graph is $y=4 \cos(x)$.

I am doing it respect to $x$. First graph can go into $x= \sqrt y$. But how would I get $x$ by itself for the second equation?

Answer (score 1):

Naively, you can just say $x=\arccos \frac y4$.  Unfortunately, because there are many values of $x$ that yield the same value of $\cos x$, we have to choose a range for the output and we usually choose $0 \le \arccos y \le \pi$  This will get you the region where $y \ge 0$.  You can get the intersection where $y \lt 0$ by negating the previous value because both $y=x^2$ and $y=4 \cos x$ are even functions

Added:  you can plot the equations in the form you were given.
[image]
To find the area between them, we note that over the region of interest $4 \cos x \ge x^2$, so our integral will be $\int_a^b (4 \cos x -x^2)dx$.  The limits of integration, $a,b$ are the $x$ coordinates of the points of intersection.  You find them by solving $4\cos x=x^2$, which you can only do numerically.  The result is about $\pm 1.20154$

Comment: I am sorry I didnt understand that. I am taking calc 2 and having difficulties. I am trying to graph the above 2 equations and find the area created but if i do it with respect to x its not an even number on the x-axis. That's why i am trying to convert it to x=?. How would i go about it?

Comment: When integrating with respect to a certain variable, that variable is the independent variable. In other words, when integrating with respect to $x$, you want your integrand to be in the form $y=f(x)$.